# Nginx and CGI is not working? i need help pleace?

Tags: nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I have a Linux Debian Weezy system with a Nginx web server and I want to access `*.cgi` scripts on my server.

I have installed `fastcgiwrapper "fcgiwrap"`.

My config looks like this:

**ngnix serverconfig:**

```
server{
....
location /cgi-bin/ {

     # Disable gzip (it makes scripts feel slower since they have to
     # complete
     # before getting gzipped)
gzip off;
     # Set the root to /usr/lib (inside this location this means that we are
     # giving access to the files under /usr/lib/cgi-bin)
root  /media/33d9d5e4-a135-4b5b-a1f0-6394a116bf32/www/server1;  #thats my webserver-root
     # Fastcgi socket
fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
     # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     # Adjust non standard parameters (SCRIPT_FILENAME)
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

  ....
}
```

**fastcgi_config:**

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
#fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $host;
fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

but I cant run some of the `*.cgi` files

I get the below error

> 502 Bad GATEWAY

and then an ngnix-log entry:

> FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: ::ffff:5.10.0.147, server: , request: "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "mein host"

The cgi-scripts in the cgi-folder have permissions to 755 and the owner and group of them are www-data (that's my webuser)

What must I do to call some of the cgi-scripts?

Comment: Is there any pattern of .cgi files which aren't called?

Comment: i have some files as cgi scripts. but i wont run 2 testscripts only. i would post codes here  now. 


`!/usr/bin/perl

use FCGI;
$cnt = 0;

while (FCGI::accept() >= 0)
{
print ("Content-type: text/html\r\
\r\
");
print ("<head>\
<title>FastCGI Demo Page (perl)</title>\
</head>\
");
print ("<h1>FastCGI Demo Page (perl)</h1>\
");
print ("This is coming from a FastCGI server.\
<BR>\
");
print ("Running on <EM>$ENV{USER}</EM> to <EM>$ENV{REMOTE_HOST}</EM>\
<BR>\
");
$cnt++;
print ("This is connection number $cnt\
");
}`

Comment: and the other testscript is 

`#!/usr/bin/perl -w
     # Tell perl to send a html header.
     # So your browser gets the output
     # rather then <stdout>(command line
     # on the server.)
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
     # print your basic html tags.
     # and the content of them.
print "<html><head><title>Hello World!! </title></head>\n";
print "<body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>\n";`